# How do I write an integration test(C++) using Catch?

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I do know that Catch is a unit testing framework. I have a server(C++) and a client(C++) to test. Is this integration testing? I am testing done functionalities in the server and some in the client that I want to test. Can I use CppUnit?
It is written in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your tests in the test cases directly. Wether those are unit tests or not is not of importance, except for the fact that:

- integration/functional tests may require environment setup/teardown in the external environment.

I wrote myself before test cases that were executed in functional or unit mode. A mock object would be used for the unit test if the command line was invoked in a certain way. If invoked in the other way, then, the functional tests would be executed. It allowed test reuse.

All in all: you can use catch or any test framework for this. There is no difference.

Comment: diago:thanks for that! Since my test needs to be for a server and 1/many clients, I wanted to know how to start the server and the clients..

Comment: I always start a server in another thread and run clients. Would that work for you?

Comment: @diago: thanks for your suggestions, I probably would be doing the same thing too, will try that and let you know how that goes.

Comment: @s_s did my question solve your problem? Let me know and tell me if you need further help.